# What data structure would support key-value pairs, that allows the keys to be ordered and amendable

Tags: data-structures, dictionary, tree, key-value

What Data Structure would support key-value pairs with the ability to order or prioritise by the key, and also allow for amending and updating of the key and permit multiple instances of same key?

Adding to the structure is not too much of a concern, incrementing the key is far more frequent and it is occasionally required to retrieve a key by a specified value.

I have already investigated DoubleLinkedLists but fear that it is not the most effective structure. I am in the process of investigating Tree structures and more specifically, Maps, Heaps and Dictionaries but could do with some guidance as each of these areas has dozens of variations.

Any suggestions would be welcome...

Comment: Sounds to me like you need a heap, perhaps augmented with a map from values to their positions in the heap. What are you implementing?

Comment: I am working on ordered amendable list for a piece of coursework, the spec certainly hints at using trees however most of the lecture material covered stacks and lists. It is basically a counting system where the counter is the key and the value is a string. To complicate matters we are not permitted to use Collections or Libraries

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest you to check for `LinkedHashMap`. In my opinion may this can be a suitable `data structure` for you.
Please have a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).